# Heat retention of parchment paper vs aluminum foil vs oven bag

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Let's say a pepper is completely but loosely wrapped in either tin foil, parchment paper, or a Reynold's oven bag (nylon or PET). Let's say the oven is maintaining a relatively constant temp.

Which would keep the heat in the food best? Also, which would take faster to get up to the temp matching the oven temperature?

Comment: Honestly, I suspect that there are too many effects in play to give a simple definitive answer from theory.  The better way to find out would be to actually perform the experiment and measure the results.

Comment: By “keep the heat,” do you mean after the food has been removed from the oven?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I meant which will be best insulated. Will the pepper in the foil or parchment or turkey bag cook faster?